Descargar dos archivos PhpSpreadsheet
Estoy creando dos archivos diferentes desde la misma base de datos, con PhpSpreadsheet.
Lo que deseo hacer es que se descarguen los dos al mismo tiempo con un solo boton, pero no logro encontrar la manera de llamar a los dos archivos.
Tengo un archivo llamado reporte1.php y reporte2.php. Pero no entiendo como integrarlos en uno solo o bien llamar a los dos desde ReporteLaboratorio.php, al mismo tiempo. Los dos archivos de manera individual si se descargan sin problema.
HTML
          <form action="../Reportes/ReporteLaboratorio.php">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
                <select name="cliente" id="cliente">
                   <option>cliente 1</option>
                   <option>cliente 2</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
                <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio">
                <label for="fecha_inicio">Fecha inicio*</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
                <input type="date" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin">
                <label for="fecha_fin">Fecha fin*</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
                <button class="btn-small green" href="">Descargar reporte<i
                    class="material-icons right">visibility</i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>


Simple, crea un boton con un id y con javascript haz que presione el boton de descargar reporte 1 y medio segundo despues haz que presione el boton de descargar reporte 2, no estas descargando ambos al mismo tiempo si no usando el script para descargarlos individualmente, funciona igual y el usuario comun ni lo notara.

Puedes utilizar fecth para descargar un archivo (o muchos), algo como:


function IniciarDescarga(){
  dialogoDescarga.showModal();
  const formData = new FormData(elForm);
  
  Descargar("URL_archivo_1",formData).then(r => Descargar(r, "archivo 1", progress1));
  
  Descargar("URL_archivo_1",formData).then(r => Descargar(r, "archivo 2", progress2));
  
}

async function Descargar(url,form){
  const result = await fetch(url, { method:"POST",body: form});
  const blob   =  await result.blob();
  return window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

function crearLink(url, nombre,fila){
  
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = nombre;
  fila.innerHtml = "";
  fila.appendChild(a);
}
<form id="elForm">
<!-- Campos del formulario -->
<input type="button" value="Descargar Archivos" onclick="IniciarDescarga()">
</form>

<dialog id="dialogoDescarga">
  <table>
    <tbdody>
      <tr>
         <td>Archivo 1</td>
         <td id="progress1"><progress></progress>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Archivo 2</td>
         <td id="progress2"><progress></progress>
      </tr>
    </tbdody> 
  </table>
</dialog>



